# Firestore Cocoapod not installing

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

When I run "pod install" I'm getting the error message

"[!] Error installing BoringSSL-GRPC
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/google/boringssl.git /var/folders/4p/459gq24124v89blbhvwjh7hc0000gn/T/d20200811-19278-1druayd --template=

Cloning into '/var/folders/4p/459gq24124v89blbhvwjh7hc0000gn/T/d20200811-19278-1druayd'...
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed"

I know that the "Firebase/firestore" is the problem. Why is this?

Podfile:

```
project 'Pordio.xcodeproj'

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Pordio' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Pordio
  pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 5.14'
  pod 'GrowingTextView', '0.7.2'
  pod 'NotificationBannerSwift', '~> 3.0.0'

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely the result of a transient network failure. Please retry.

Comment: Do you mean my Internet connection?

Comment: Yes. It's likely related to the internet connection being flaky somewhere.